# Magento 2 CSS - Trying to target home page only with .cms-home but styling affects other pages too

Tags: magento2, css, less-css

I am using the Magento 2.1.6 blank theme as a base for my own theme which is working correctly.

However, I want to add CSS code to target the home page only and not affect any other pages.

I have added this to _theme_extend.less (which I think is the correct location):

```
.cms-home h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;;
}
```

However, when I go to another CMS page (which definitely does NOT have the class cms-home) it still picks up the padding and applies it. Here's a screenshot showing what the browser is rendering:

Can anyone help with what I have done wrong?

[image: CSS output in browser]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change:

```
.cms-home h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;;
}
```

to

```
.cms-home h1, .cms-home h2, .cms-home h3, .cms-home h4, .cms-home h5, .cms-home h6, .cms-home p {
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;;
}
```

to apply your css to home page only.

Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much! (I had spent all morning on google trying to figure this out for myself)